# How do I prevent "end process tree" from terminating the programs mine has started?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to execute an EXE 'two.exe' from another application 'one.exe' in Delphi XE2 using ShellExecute.

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'two.exe', nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

It works perfectly, but whenever I terminate application 'one.exe' (the parent app) from Task Manager's process tab, using the "end process tree" option, the application 'two.exe' also gets terminated.

How can I prevent my ShellExecuted application from getting terminated like this?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're explaining...   like you explain: `ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', PWideChar(ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)), nil, PWideChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)), SW_SHOWNORMAL);`
Don't kill the other instances...  `ShellExecute(0, 'open', PWideChar(ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName)), nil, PWideChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)), SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: Are you sure there is not some other interaction between the two apps that would cause the second app to close when the first is closed?

Comment: I can reproduce it. Exactly as described in the question. In Process Explorer there is a view of the processes that clearly shows the group hierarchy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree with Process Explorer.. but with the regular TaskManager, when I end the process tree, it doesn't kill my child app if my first argument is 0...

Comment: `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` looks like the thing to use. But I can't make it work.

Comment: +1. Just as a note: Unless you know for sure that the file association for a file extension has a specific verb assigned, don't use one. (For instance, .exe in HKCR does not have an `open` verb, it has `run`. You shouldn't use `open`.) Just use `nil` instead when you want the default action to take place, and let Windows figure out what to do; it will automatically open Word document (`.doc`) files, run executables, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to create an intermediate process which in turn spawns `two.exe`. You then need the intermediate process to terminate immediately, at which point the relationship between the original process and `two.exe` is broken.

Comment: After some search without result, I agree as I don't think it's possible to update the [th32ParentProcessID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1857762/596852) which is probably used by Process Explorer...

Answer (score 12):

Ok, not very nice solution... but tested with success ;o)

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd', 
  PChar('/C  start "" "' + Application.ExeName + '"'), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

[image]

The first is manually launched... his child with regular shellexecute call...
The last one, with the shellexecute **+** cmd trick...

[/C explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515867/send-parameter-to-cmd)

Comment: This is an implementation of the method in my answer. Downside, I guess, is that a command window flashes up for a second.

Comment: Yes, that's an implemantation of your explanation... but I swear I haven't copied.. I was testing it when you post it and saw it after ;o)

Comment: Oh I didn't mean to imply that. I just wanted to add an explanation of how this technique works.

Comment: @Tlama Right, I see that now.

Comment: @Whiler I added something to the code so that it would cope with programs that contain spaces in their names. +1 by the way.

Comment: don't you add too much (or is it the website formating...) (after the start..)

Comment: try it without the seemingly spurious `""`. You will find that does not work and is interpreted as the window title. Look at `start /?` to understand why.